# How can I join WMV files in Windows?

Tags: windows, video-editing

How can I easily join video files with WMV extension in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use Windows Movie Maker to join wmv files. [This site](http://www.windowsmoviemakers.net/) is a good source for Windows Movie Maker stuff including tutorials, tips, effects etc.

Answer (score 0):

try with virtualdub ( http://www.virtualdub.org/ )
maybe using the wmv plugin ( http://home.comcast.net/~fcchandler/Plugins/WMV/index.html )