# Merging WMV files losslessly

Tags: video, wmv

Note:  There is a related question but all answers for it are now dead or don't work for me.

[How can I join WMV files in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/84456/how-can-i-join-wmv-files-in-windows)

I have several .wmv files that are in a few pieces.  As the resolution and encoding is a match a direct stream merge should be possible.

Indeed, Boilsoft's video joiner was willing to reassemble **some** of them perfectly.  I have some others that have failed with everything I have attempted.

The one I have been using as my test candidate is 70 minutes, sliced into three approximately equal parts.

Boilsoft's program assembles this into a 28 minute file.

Avidemux 2.6.10 produces an .avi but fast enough I think it was a direct copy rather than a reencode.  It's the right size and the right runtime but trashed.

Asfbin produces a 28 minute file that's way too small.  Run on individual pieces it produces files that are way too small, they play correctly but only part way through--yet claim to have the correct runtime.

Comment: What version of Windows and how much RAM is avail in Task Mgr?

Comment: You're complaining that it wasn't a reencode while you want it to be lossless. If you want it to be lossless you can't reencode but would have to use something like a direct stream copy. As for the linked question, the availability of Movie Maker depends on your Windows version and the VirtualDub solution is still available by simply trying to find the [plugin](http://gral.y0.pl/~fcchandler/Plugins/WMV/) using google. Have you tried both? What system are you using? [Try this](http://lparchive.org/techsupport/guide-norecompress.html)?

Comment: The WMV plug-in lets VirtualDub **read** a .wmv but the merge option only shows .avi and is grayed out.  I'm running Windows 7, no Movie Maker.  As for your last link, what are you pointing to?  I see nothing there that looks like a video editor.

Comment: @TonyStewart Win7/64, gobs of ram.

Answer (score 0):

Use ffpmeg as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373401/403455). All of the files will have to be encoded using the same parameters. I just tested it and it works perfectly.